# Espacio en blanco detras del background angular 8/9 ¿como establecer bien el background?

Tags: html, css, angular, background

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo establecido una foto en resolucion 1440x900 como background de mi pagina web, el problema es que tiene unos margenes en blanco que no se como quitarlos, quiero que la foto cubra absolutamente toda la pantalla.

-codigo de app.html(donde declaro el fondo de pantalla para empezar a escribir)(el app-header es la nav-bar con los botones que esos si quiero que tengan su propio fondo a color como ya esta puesto) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-codigo del app.css donde tengo establecido el fondo de pantalla[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-asi se ve mi pagina, donde tambien se puede ver los bordes blancos alrededor de mi fondo que quiero quitar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tu código HTML y tú regla css como texto por favor

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor considera hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) donde aprenderás sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y ganarás tu primera medalla. Para mejorar tus oportunidades de obtener una respuesta, agrega tu código en texto como lo sugiere @BetaM y no en imagenes.

Comment: Utilizas un reset en el css? Si no lo utilizas por favor prueba `body{margin:0;padding:0}`

Comment: @enxaneta no se a que te refieres con reset, pero dentro del css de app ingrese lo que me dijiste, y arreglo el margen derecho, en el izquierdo sigue un espacio en blanco y arriba, abajo tambien

Answer (score 1):

**Buenas noches**
Lo que puedes intentar seria lo siguiente:

**app.component.html** 
*Borrar el div con el nombre background y dejar solo el componente header*

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

En los estilos generales (styles.css):

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height 100%;
}
```

**app.component.css**
*Puede usar el selector `:host` para hacer referencia al contenedor app-component y asi no es necesario hacer wrappers o div contenedores*

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(......);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando lo que @enxaneta, si sigue pasando después de revisar que no sea algún otro elemento que esté interfiriendo con el margen, usa `margin: 0 0`. En teoría solo un 0 debería hacer que le aplique a las 4 márgenes, pero me ha funcionado más especificarle que lo aplique así.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer]. Además podrás conseguir algunos puntos, para poder comentar en cualquier pregunta.